# What database columns needed to upload video in rails - Carrierwave, Fog & S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I would like users to be able to upload videos to my rails site using carrierwave, fog and Amazon S3. (I haven't tried to implement S3 for storage yet and is not the subject of this questions.)

What database columns do I need for my video model and model save code to successfully save a video file using Carrierwave?

At the moment I have the following for my Video table but im confused as to what i really need.

```
 class CreateVideoTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    create_table :videos do |t|
      t.string :video
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :question_id
      t.string :youtube_url
      t.string :type
      t.string :filename
      t.string :checksum
      t.string :path
      t.integer :filesize
      t.integer :width
      t.integer :height
      t.integer :duration
      t.integer :bit_rate

      t.timestamps
    end
      add_index :videos, [:user_id, :question_id]
  end

  def down
    remove_index :videos, [:user_id, :question_id]
    drop_table :videos
  end
end
```

This is how my Video model looks:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :user_id, :question_id, :video, :youtube_url, :type, :filename, :checksum, :path, :filesize, :width, :height, :duration, :bit_rate

  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user

  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
end
```

and finally my carrierwave uploader.

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(ogg ogv 3gp mp4 m4v webm mov m2v 3g2)
    # %w(ogg ogv 3gp mp4 m4v webm mov)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to put `storage :fog`

Otherwise, in the model, you only need a string column `video` for storing the S3 URL. Carrierwave/fog will take care of the rest. You can of course add more columns relevant to your application if needed.
In other words, you are good to go :)

Also, the initializer is missing, don't know if you forgot it:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy',                        # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                     # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```